# Removed Permissions from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and now Win 2k8 server won't boot

Tags: windows

So long story short I am working on a Lab assignment for a class that is having us edit the Windows Registry(No mention of backing up registry before making changes and late at night me decides to take the risk.)

I modified the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key permissions with the lab materials and all of the other permissions were deleted from the object. So now I have HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT which only has read permissions for the "Server Operators" group on the Windows 2008 R2 server. What would be the best way of fixing the registry? The server will no longer boot, it just displays a blue screen saying errors in booting. Recovery environment still works, Last good known configuration does not work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I was able to find a folder within /Windows/System32/config called regBackups. This folder had a registry backup from a few days ago. I restored the SOFTWARE.reg hive to the /Windows/System32/config folder and was able to restore the original permissions to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and get the machine to boot. It also turns out that the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Classes and that hive is actually mounted from there.

Hope this solution helps others in the future with a similar problem.